# How send GPS location from android to asp.net mvc

Tags: android, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc, rest

I m New In Programming World This Is My Final Year Project Please Help Stackoverflow community

Comment: First of all, if you want us to help you, you must show what have you done so far. Then we can help you.

Comment: At first you should an API so that it will save the data to your database. Use JSON to to interchange data. To send GPS coordinate its very easy. There are many video tutorial available in YouTube. Good luck...

Comment: I m Done Web Api And Api Return Json Data Please Guide How to Json Data CRUD operation On Android To Asp.net Mvc

Comment: @OsamaDanish In English, we don't capitalize every word in a sentence. Only the first letter of each sentence, and then proper nouns within sentences. See [Proper Noun on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_noun#Capitalization). It's very distracting to capitalize every single word.

Comment: Sorry @mason =D

Answer (score 0):

Following are the steps You need to do ..

1. make api on mvc use this link [MVC API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api).
2. make a post api so that it can resive the data from android.
3. Use [Volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html) to send data to mvc server (i-e api ) .
4. your done :D